# 1 of these 2 request apparently equivalent is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to understand how PIVOT table works

These 2 requests with pivot table seem equivalent:

I only write
tablename.column1, ...........column2 instead of tablename.*

You can find the requests here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5c3aacdaebe599bb050295caf3512b6

```
with
    a as
(   
    select
        a1.column_value a, a2.column_value b , cos(a1.r) c
    from
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5))) a1 ,
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('a','b','a','b','a'))) a2
    where
        a1.r   = a2.r)
select a.a,a.b,a.c from a --a.a,a.b
PIVOT
(
  count(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
)
```

```
ORA-00904: "A"."C": invalid identifier
```

```
with
    a as
(   
    select
        a1.column_value a, a2.column_value b , cos(a1.r) c
    from
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5))) a1 ,
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('a','b','a','b','a'))) a2
    where
        a1.r   = a2.r)
select * from a
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
)
```

intended result

Comment: Ok, If you downgrade the question but please say my why.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud this is a valid and interesting question. You were downgraded because you only posted a link at the beginning. The question in this state is now OK, but people just went back to remove their -1 vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a PIVOT, Oracle will name the resulting columns just like their original values.
You can see this behavior when you do your `select *` that is working :

```
with
    a as
(   
    select
        a1.column_value a, a2.column_value b , cos(a1.r) c
    from
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5))) a1 ,
        (select column_value, rownum r from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('a','b','a','b','a'))) a2
    where
        a1.r   = a2.r)
select * from a
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
)
```

result is

```
C                                          'a' 'b'
-.65364362086361191463916818309775038145    0   1
.5403023058681397174009366074429766037354   1   0
-.98999249660044545727157279473126130238    1   0
.2836621854632262644666391715135573083265   1   0
-.41614683654714238699756822950076218977    0   1
```

Your columns headings have been turned by Oracle into the exact values you've got in the `IN` clause, including the surrounding quotes.

So to refer them in your SELECT clause, you should use double quotes like this:

```
select "'a'","'b'", c from a 
PIVOT
(
  count(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
)
```

An alternative is to alias your values directly in the `IN` clause

```
select val_a, val_b, c from a --a.a,a.b
PIVOT
(
  count(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a' val_a, 'b' val_b )
)


VAL_A   VAL_B   C
0       1       -.65364362086361191463916818309775038145
1       0       .5403023058681397174009366074429766037354
1       0       -.98999249660044545727157279473126130238
1       0       .2836621854632262644666391715135573083265
0       1       -.41614683654714238699756822950076218977
```

And finally, you had another mistake in your initial approach:

```
select a.a,a.b,a.c from a --a.a,a.b
PIVOT
(
  count(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
)
```

in this query `a` refers to your initial `a` CTE. When you do `a.a,a.b,a.c`, Oracle doesn't know what you are referencing because of the PIVOT that comes afterwards.

You should properly alias the PIVOT results if you want to refer to it in the SELECT clause :

```
select pa."'a'",pa."'b'", pa.c from a 
PIVOT
(
  count(a.a)--,sum(a.c)
  FOR b IN ('a', 'b')
) pa
```